# How to use delegate to performSegue in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, delegates, segue

I have 3 classes :
`Core` that doesn't inherit from any class.
`vcMain` and `vcIncomingFile` which both inherit from `UIViewController`.

I have a segue from `vcMain` to `vcIncomingFile`.
How can I call the `-performSegueWithIdentifier:` method from the Core class,between `vcMain` and `vcIncoming`. I mean I want to have a method or delegate or anything else in Core class that can performSegue from `vcMain` to `vcIncomingFile`.

```
class Core {
    func showIncomingVC(){ }
}
```

in `showIncomingVC` function, I want to `performSegue` between `vcMain` and `vcIncomingFile`.
Thanks

Comment: How and where is `Core` instantiated?

Comment: Core is the network communication class. It instantiated in another class called vcAcceptance. It send,analyze and receive commands from network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement the patterns properly we would need to know if your Core class is part of your model or if it is some kind of control flow mechanism.

If it is part of the model, it should know nothing about the view controllers but the view controllers are allowed to access it.   In this case your view controllers could implement a delegate protocol of some sort and establish a call path from your Core class by assigning themselves as a delegate for some part of the Core functionality.  The Core could then trigger any pre-defined behaviour in its delegates by calling the methods defined in the protocol.

For example,

If you define a protocol called FileEventDelegate with a method named fileReceived().

Then, add a member to your Core class called fileEventDelegate of type FileEventDelegate?

Whenever the Core class receives a file, it can call fileEventDelegate?.fileReceived(). The object instance, of whichever class implements the protocol, that registered itself as the delegate will handle it from there.
A unit testing class could also be the delegate and not even have nor need a segue to be performed.
Your Core class could even work without a delegate being set.

On the UI side, your VcMain class can implement the FileEventDelegate protocol by defining a fileReceived() function that call performSegueWithIdentifier(...). On viewLoaded() it can set itself as the fileEventDelegate of the Core class instance it is working with.

This keeps all model-to-visual logic in the viewController where it belongs.

If your Core class works in complete separation of the view controllers (meaning that the view controllers don't know how to access the instance(s) of Core), you may want to look into NSNotificationCenter and send notifications out in the universe for your viewControllers to pick-up asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I defined the protocol and the method with it. And for vcMain I implement protocol and make it conform to it. I add a member of protocolDelegate to Core. But now how and where to register delegate? I mean this line "The object instance, of whichever class implements the protocol, that registered itself as the delegate will handle it from there."

Comment: Thanks a lot. I defined the protocol and the method with it. And for vcMain I implement protocol and make it conform to it. I add a member of protocolDelegate to Core. But now how and where to register delegate? I mean this line "The object instance, of whichever class implements the protocol, that registered itself as the delegate will handle it from there." @alain-t

Comment: The assumption on "registering itself" is that your view controller can either instantiate or find an instance of the Core class and set its fileEventDelegate property to self.    For example, if you Core class has a singleton (e.g. a static variable such as sharedInstance) with an instance of the class, then your vcMain can do Core.shareInstance.fileEventDelegate = self in its ViewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 0):

`Core` needs to be of `UIViewController` or some class that inherit `UIViewController` because `performSegueWithIdentifier` is a function of UIViewController

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:

You can work with protocol instead. Create a protocol in your Core class with func showIncomingVC(){ } and use its delegate in your view class

Comment: Yes I know that I can make Core be a sub class of UIViewController,but MVC pattern will go wrong. I want work with protocols and delegate. But I dont know how exactly,I search about it,but I face some errors. Can you explain how to use delegates? Thanks

Comment: The answer above there is the simple way to work with protocol and class,  just change the identifier name that you used in your storyboard inside the struct

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this:

```
struct Segue {
    let sourceVC: UIViewController
    let sender: AnyObject
    let identifier: String
}

protocol SegueProtocol: class {
    var segue: Segue { get }
}

class Core {
    weak var delegate: SegueProtocol?
    func perform() {
        guard let segue = delegate?.segue else {
            return
        }
        segue.sourceVC.performSegueWithIdentifier(segue.identifier, sender: segue.sender)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, in struct closure: I got an error for UIViewController "Use of undeclared type "UIViewController" How can I solve it?

Comment: Thanks I forgot to inport UIKit. Error has been solved.

Comment: @BehdadAhmadi Just import UIKit

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just How and where to tell about my Segue Identifier? Sorry If it feels stupid question.

Comment: @BehdadAhmadi You should make your view controller confirm to SegueProtocol. All info is in segue. And then set it Core's delegate. And just call perform().

Comment: An erorr " Type "vcMain" does not conform to protocol "SegueProtocol"   , vcMain is sub class of UIViewController.

Comment: @BehdadAhmadi Make it conform to SegueProtocol .